# PHP Socket error: socket_connect(): Host lookup failed [-10001]: Unknown host in /usr/local/nginx/html/test1.php

Tags: php, sockets, nginx

I write a simple socket server on one computer:

```
<?php
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if(!socket_bind($socket, 'localhost', 52222)){
    exit(socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)));
}
if(!socket_listen($socket)){
    exit(socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)));
}
$conn = socket_accept($socket);
if(!$conn){
    exit(socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)));
}


socket_write($conn, "250 HAHA\r\n");
```

It listens on 52222, and I use `netstat -tnlp` can find it listens on 52222 successfully.

On another computer I write a simple client,

```
<?php
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if(socket_connect($socket, 'http://192.168.161.133', 52222)){
    exit(socket_strerror($socket_last_error($socket)));
}
```

but when I run it, an error happened

```
PHP Warning:  socket_connect(): Host lookup failed [-10001]: Unknown host in /usr/local/nginx/html/test1.php on line 3
```

I had close firewall on both computer.

Comment: *http:// 192.168.161.133* is no address, change it to 192.168.161.133 without protocol [http] and make sure, that adress is reachable

Comment: I had changed it to 192.168.161.133, and I'm sure that this address is reachable by using command ping